# How can testing a ASP.NET using Integrated Windows Authentication web app with LOCUST or GATLİNG

Tags: testing, performance-testing, windows-authentication, gatling, locust

İ want to write load testing asp.net web app using gatling or locus but this app use windows authentication..

How can ı do that .. Thank you.